# csv.writer - How to dynamically write columns in writerow(n1,n2,n3, ...nth)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I am trying to write to a CSV file. I want to write three variables on a row and then write a variable number of columns.

So for example my script will do a bunch of calculations and come up with the idea that I need 12 columns.
So the 'variable' needs to contain column 0 thru 11.

How to do this dynamically?

```
numberofcolumns = 12
with open(f+".csv",'wb') as output_csvfile:
    filewriter = csv.writer(output_csvfile)
    filewriter.writerow([constant1,constant2,constant3,variable[0],...,variable[n]])
```

What I want is to do 
`filewriter.writerow([constant1, constant2, constant3, variable[0], variable[1],....,variable[11]])`
However variable[11] may not be 11 it may be 8 or 10 or whatever. the length is dynamic. How can I make it so that this code will be able to output to Nth column if the function writerow() isn't defined to use *args?

Comment: Do you need help in filling `variable` with the values, or how to write them once you've filled 'variable'?  (Note that `variable` does not appear anywhere in your code.)

Comment: Please specify exactly what you want and if possible, what error you get when you are trying your own code.

Comment: variable appears in `filewriter.writerow([constant1,constant2,constant3,variable])`

Comment: `writerow()` will accept a sequence of any length as an argument, so just create one on-the-fly with the column data you want in it. Note that csv files should be `open()`ed with the option `newline=''` in Python 3.

Comment: What I want is to do `filewriter.writerow([constant1, constant2, constant3, variable[0], variable[1],....,variable[11]])`  However variable[11] may not be 11 it may be 8 or 10 or whatever. the length is dynamic. How can I make it so that this code will be able to output to Nth column if the function writerow() isn't defined to use *args?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What martineau pointed out in a comment is correct. `writerow` accepts a list, or sequence, of any length.

So you *could* do something like the following:

```py
variable = range(12)

# Change your writerow line to be something like this: 
filewriter.writerow([constant1,constant2,constant3] + variable)
```

`range` in this case is an example of creating a list of however-many items. [`range` is documented here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range).

Notice that the above example uses `+` to put two sequences/lists together.

Here's an example of that from the command line/[repl](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/interpreter.html#interactive-mode):

```
>>> variable = range(12)
>>> variable
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
>>> ["x", "y", "z"] + variable
['x', 'y', 'z', 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
```